# No such file or directory #include <QDebug>

Tags: qt, qdebug

Why I got an error:

I use Qt Creator. Version Qt 5.9.7 for Desktop

Output::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

```
23:02:13: Uruchamianie "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../Kurs_STL_cpp0x -I. -I../../anaconda3/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o main.o ../Kurs_STL_cpp0x/main.cpp
../Kurs_STL_cpp0x/main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: Debug: No such file or directory
 #include <Debug>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:627: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
23:02:13: Proces "/usr/bin/make" zakończył się kodem wyjściowym 2.
Błąd budowania / instalowania projektu Kurs_STL_cpp0x (zestaw narzędzi: Desktop)
Podczas wykonywania kroku "Make"
23:02:13: Czas trwania: 00:00.
```

Comment: Could you provide the compile output? It seems your include paths are incomplete.

Comment: Done...........

Comment: I need the whole compile output (or at least, the build commands).

Comment: Ok. Done.   good?            .

Comment: The Qt includes are missing. Check if your .pro file contains a line like `CONFIG -= qt` and remove it (it happens if you create a non-Qt project in Qt Creator)

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you will add an answer and I will accept solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you select a non-Qt project, the generated *.pro file is configured to disable Qt (and you will not be able to include Qt files).

In *.pro file, remove the line `CONFIG -= qt` to enable Qt.

After that, you may need to include the different Qt modules (widgets, quick, etc.) by adding them to the env variable QT (the module core and gui should be enabled by default).

For example, to use the Qt Widgets and Qt Quick, you have to add `QT += widgets quick`

You can also disable useless modules by adding a line like `QT -= gui`